# Nestjs Test Unit

Tags: unit-testing

Im try to test unit in Nestjs

But its showing error

```
Test suite failed to run

Cannot find module '@nestjs/core/inspector/graph-inspector' from '../node_modules/@nestjs/testing/testing-module.builder.js'

Require stack:
  /Volumes/My Files/IdeaProjects/ChecklistApp/server/node_modules/@nestjs/testing/testing-module.builder.js
  /Volumes/My Files/IdeaProjects/ChecklistApp/server/node_modules/@nestjs/testing/test.js
  /Volumes/My Files/IdeaProjects/ChecklistApp/server/node_modules/@nestjs/testing/index.js
  task/task.spec.ts
```

Answer (score 8):

I have same problem with you, and i solved it. This problem is occurred because  "@nestjs/core/inspector/graph-inspector" **is missing** but still referenced in "../node_modules/@nestjs/testing/testing-module.builder.js".

To solve this problem do following command:

```
npm i @nestjs/core && npm i @nestjs/testing
```

***Note: above command will update the version of @nestjs/core and @nestjs/testing package to the latest version.***

Comment: Thank you Matahari. This also fixed a very similar error `"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'inspectInstanceWrapper')"`.

Comment: @alexkb you're welcome, im happy to be able to help people.

Comment: @MatahariRamadhan i have the same problem. Problem is i already have @nestjs/core and @nestjs/testing installed.

Comment: @KaisinLi The issue is that the version of @nestjs/core doesn't match with @nestjs/testing. This means that @nestjs/testing/testing-module.builder.js still relies on @nestjs/core/inspector/graph-inspector, but it can't locate the module. By installing or updating both @nestjs/core and @nestjs/testing, these two packages will be aligned, and everything will function properly.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I also had to install/update @nestjs/common

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).